Quillen-Suslin theorem for non-strict polydiscs in the sense of Berkovich
Let $K$ be a complete non-archimedean field of mixed characteristic $(0,p)$. Choose $\rho_1,\dots,\rho_n\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and let $P$ be a finite projective module over $K\langle\rho_1^{-1}t_1,\dots,\rho^{-1}_n t_n \rangle$. It is already known that if $\rho_i\in \sqrt{|K^\times|}$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$, then $P$ is free. This is Proposition 6.6 of "Full faithfulness for overconvergent F -isocrystals" by Kedlaya.
Proof of the author relies on the condition that the polydisc is strictly affinoid, because in the proof one have to choose some $u\in K$ such that the value of a power of $u$ equals to $\rho_i$.
I want to know whether the same argument holds when some $\rho_i\notin \sqrt{|K^\times|}$. In particular, it is known that the case where $n=1$ is true because in this case $K\langle \rho^{-1}t\rangle$ is a PID.
